# Is it possible to use "quietly = TRUE" in lapply?

Tags: r

I'm using `lapply` function in R to load several packages at once but I would like it to quietly load them. Is this possible or do I need to change my approach?

Here is the code I'm running:

```
packages <- c("ggplot2", "caret", "corrplot")
lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE)
```

I tried to use `quietly=TRUE` but it didn't work with `lapply`.

Comment: I use `invisible(lapply(packages, require, character.only=TRUE))`?

Comment: @AdamQuek , please post as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`invisible` in tandem with `require` will supress all the confirming messages, as well as hiding the lapply output for loading mutliple packages:

```
packages <- c("ggplot2", "caret", "corrplot")
invisible(lapply(packages, require, character.only=TRUE, quietly=TRUE))
```

Comment: and it will (invisibly) return a boolean list (or vector if you use sapply) so you can verify that all packages have been loaded successfully